# WPF FrameworkElement not receiving Mouse input

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, frameworkelement, routedevent

Trying to get OnMouse events appearing in a child `FrameworkElement`. The parent element is a `Panel` (and the `Background` property is not Null).

```
class MyFrameworkElement : FrameworkElement
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Trying to get here!
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
}

public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is OK
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
}
```

OnMouse never gets called, event is always unhandled and Snoop tells me that the routed event only ever seems to get as far as the `Panel` element.

```
<Window 
  x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
  Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <Border x:Name="myBorder" Background="Red">
    <l:MyPanel x:Name="myPanel" Background="Transparent">
      <l:MyFrameworkElement x:Name="myFE"/>
    </l:MyPanel>
  </Border>
</Window>
```

Docs say that `FrameworkElement` handles Input, but why not in this scenario?

Answer (score 23):

`OnMouseDown` will only be called if your element responds to Hit Testing.  See [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).  The default implementation will do hit testing against the graphics drawn in [`OnRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender.aspx).  Creating a `Panel` with a `Transparent` background works because `Panel` draws a rectangle over its entire area, and that rectangle will catch the hit test.  You can get the same effect by overriding `OnRender` to draw a transparent rectangle:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, null, 
        new Rect(0, 0, RenderSize.Width, RenderSize.Height));
}
```

You could also override [`HitTestCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.hittestcore.aspx) so that all clicks are counted as hits:

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the scenario you described. I did some playing around, and it wasn't until I changed the base class of `MyFrameworkElement` from `FrameworkElement` to something more concrete, like `UserControl` that events started firing like they should. I'm not 100% sure why this would be, but I would recommend using one of the classes derived from `FrameworkElement` that would suit your needs (like `Panel`, as you did in the example above, or `Button`).

I'd be curious to know the exact reason your example above produces these results...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been playing around for a little bit and managed to get the behaviour I need by adding the following to FrameWorkElement:

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            Size renderSize = this.RenderSize;
            Rect rect = new Rect(renderSize);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Transparent, 0.0);
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, pen, rect);
        }

Perhaps FrameworkElement is zero in size unless something is added to it?